# Spring Security OAuth2: InsufficientAuthenticationException

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

First of all, I disabled basic auth:

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

Then I access the authorization page:

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?client_id=client&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://www.baidu.com
```

I got following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:138) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at ...
```

I don't understand why I have to do authentication first before OAuth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flow for the authorization code grant goes like this:

1. Client redirects the user to auth server's authorization page. Hence the `http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?client_id=client&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://www.baidu.com`
2. If the user were already logged in, the user would be immediately shown an authorization page where he can approve the authorization request. **If the user is not yet logged in, he should be redirected to a login page first to authenticate himself** to let Spring Security know who is giving the authorization.

What you probably need to do is secure the authorization endpoint by requiring a role granted like this in xml:

```
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true"
               use-expressions="true"
               entry-point-ref="loginEntryPoint">
    ...

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/authorize" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    ...
</security:http>
```

If the user is not yet logged in, this will trigger Spring Security to redirect the user to login as configured in your `loginEntryPoint`. Typically, you would redirect the user to a login page. After successfully authenticating, the user will return to the authorization endpoint.

Comment: What if the server is stateless ? It has no session. My authorization server could have a login controller or filter, but how would it notify Spring Security that the user credentials are correct ?

Comment: @Stephane your authorization server needs to have session enabled. You can scale your application by relying on something like redis to do the session management.

Comment: I configured my authorization server to authenticate using a JWT access token, with a login filter creating the token, and passing the token in a header when sending a request to the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint. This way I skip using the session and my authorization server is stateless.