# InsufficientAuthenticationException at Spring Boot OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have created `Authorization Server` and `Resource Server` with Spring Boot OAuth2 and it works fine with `password` grant type.

I want to test Authorization Code Flow from Postman. I send such a request to get an access code:

```
http://localhost:1111/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=test_client&redirect_uri=www.test_something.com
```

However, I get an error as follows:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-09-27T21:02:14Z",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException",
    "message": "User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.",
    "path": "/oauth/authorize"
}
```

I've tried to send username and password at `Basic Authentication HTTP headers` but didn't work. I've also send such parameters as form parameters in a `POST` request and but didn't work too.

How can I make it work? Should I enable a login page for it?

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424176/spring-security-oauth2-insufficientauthenticationexception

Comment: Doesn't work for my case.

Comment: Why do you use Postman? You have to use a browser. However, show your authorization server configuration.